# How to trigger PHP script when a record is inserted in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, insert, record

How to trigger PHP script when a record is inserted in MySQL database? I want to insert record through one PHP file and want to trigger a script to update another page.

Comment: Is there a reason that the first PHP script cannot start the second one?

Comment: MySQL isn't really able to execute arbitrary PHP scripts. You will need a PHP triggering PHP type of solution here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two PHP files, you could then `require('..')` the file at the top of the first PHP page.  If both of the files are in the same directory you could use `require('file2.php');` or `require('/folder/file2');` if it is in a directory within the current one.

All that would be required is in the first file (after the SQL query) you can call a function defined within the second PHP file, where you could then do what you need to.

Answer (score 0):

General Flow Can be ..

There is one PHP that handle Inserts , if there is an insert lets say that you run a select before to check if the record is new / unique prior to the insert . 
If this is a new record and you insert this run this type of command -> file_get_content('example.com/script2.php')

If row is not new / unique -> Do nothig..